# iOS: saving UIImageView to Camera Roll

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, camera-roll

Even though this sounds super simple, I got stuck on this because of how my app works.

I have a `UIImageView` that loads an online image. On the app, I will have a button that gives the user a choice to export the image to Camera Roll.

Most solutions such as `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` don't work with `UIImageView`.

Should I first capture a `UIImage` from the `UIImageView` and then save to Camera Roll? How? Or can I save directly?

Comment: Yes, you need to save the `UIImage`, not `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 2):

The `UIImage` is a representation of an image. `UIImageView` is a container for displaying that image in your app. What you need to save is the image, not the container.